# Request url path in jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, api, jax-rs

so i have this jax-rs REST project and ive never used jax in my life.

what id like to do (probably not the right way) is when someone requests something from my api they should 
type **url.com/token/path/sub-path/**

id like to collect the : **/token/path/sub-path/** part, even better put it in an array like this :
**[token,path,sub-path]**

the project says i should use filters. i also have another issue where when im in the filter class i dont know how to output data, to either the web page or even  my eclipse console.

```
package com.di3;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.di3.admin.AdminHandler;

public class LoginFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
    @Context
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //do some token checking!
        System.out.println(token);
    }

}
```

thank you very much and sorry if the questions are silly or something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: Using ```request.getUriInfo().getPathSegments()``` is the way to go. It will return a ```List<PathSegment>``` collection. [Here is the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html) which helps how to collect exploded segments and those names.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, but how do i output what im working on? System.out.println("test") shows nothing on the console. thank you.

Comment: ok it worked seems i forgot to add @Provider on my filter ,thank you for the help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) In addition to @zforgo's comment I suggest that you do not add all those negative statements towards yourself like "silly" or "not the right way". While yes, this is beginning level question, we've all been beginners once :) In addition those statements make reception of a question bit harder. Focus on technical part and remember none was born with knowledge about `jax-rs REST`

Comment: @GrayCat thanks i appreciate the input, i can now REST in peace.